# Sum element during foreach with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to sum each `<a class="active">` found on my page and make the sum of the `data-value="0"` containing in the `<li>` parent.

Here is my try:

```js
var total = 0;
$('a.active').each(function(){
    total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).parent().data('value'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).parent().data('value'));
    console.log(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs-outline">
    <li class="nav-item" data-value="0">
        <a class="nav-link">No</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-value="50">
        <a class="nav-link active">Yes
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs-outline">
    <li class="nav-item" data-value="0">
        <a class="nav-link">No</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-value="150">
        <a class="nav-link active">Yes
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs-outline">
    <li class="nav-item" data-value="0">
        <a class="nav-link active">No</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-value="75">
        <a class="nav-link">Yes
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So the total should be `200`.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Side note; `data()` will auto parse number for you.  `parseInt()` is unnecessary

Comment: `var total = $('a.active').closest('.nav-item[data-value]').map(it=>$(it).data('value')).get().reduce((total, number)=>total+=number, 0);`

Comment: I've converted your code parts into a snippet. As you can see the result is, as expected, `200`. Please modify it into a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.